# Rearrange table using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with customer IDs and emails. Some users have multiple emails. The table looks something like this:

```
| Customer  | Email          |
| ----------| -------------- |
| 1         | jdoe@mail.com  |
| 2         | jane1@mail.com |
| 3         | adam@mail.com  |
| 1         | john_d@mail.com|
```

What I would like to do is rearrange the table such that each customer ID has only one row and secondary emails are added as additional columns. Something like this:

```
| Customer  | Email1         |Email2         |
| ----------| -------------- |---------------|
| 1         | jdoe@mail.com  |john_d@mail.com
| 2         | jane1@mail.com |               |
| 3         | adam@mail.com  |               |
```

What's the best way to do this using pandas? I have tried using df.pivot but that doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Are you really sure you want it this way? What if 1 user has 10 Emails, or 99? Please elaborate why you think this is nesessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Series.duplicated()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html?highlight=duplicates) + [`pd.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.merge) + [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html?highlight=drop_duplicated)

```
# We get the Customers with more than one email.
df_seconds_email = df[df['Customer'].duplicated()]

# We merge your original dataframe (I called it 'df') and the above one, suffixes param help us to get
# 'Email2' column, finally we drop duplicates taking into account 'Customer' column.
df = pd.merge(df, df_seconds_email, how='left', on=['Customer'], suffixes=('', '2')).drop_duplicates(subset='Customer')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Customer    Email          Email2
0      1    jdoe@mail.com   john_d@mail.com
1      2    jane1@mail.com      NaN
2      3    adam@mail.com       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cumcount` to  create MultiIndex. Then reshape the data by using `unstack` and add change columns names by `add_prefix`:

```
    df = (df.set_index(['Customer',df.groupby('Customer').cumcount()])['Email']
        .unstack()
        .add_prefix('Email')
        .reset_index())
    print(df)
```

And you'll get exactly what you want.